# JMS Topic Creation in JBoss 5 AS

Tags: jboss, jms

In Jboss 4, when I deployed an ear with an MDB for a topic that had not been specified in the deployment descriptors, the server would automatically create the topic (after posting a warning saying that topic didn't exist).

In Jboss 5, it doesn't seem to automatically create the topics anymore (errors out instead). Is there a configuration option somewhere that would allow automatic topic creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JBoss community forums -- [This JIRA](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-6013) was added in 5AS.

Unfortunately it looks like there is no way to implement createDestination globally in the standardjboss.xml descriptor -- You have to add a custom jboss.xml descriptor to the ear deploying the mdb.

```
<jboss xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss_5_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <enterprise-beans>
       <message-driven>
          <ejb-name>MessageDriven</ejb-name>
          <create-destination>true</create-destination>
       </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</jboss>
```