# How to auto create a JMS topic/queue on JBoss in a portable and per-application way?

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss-mdb

It's simple: I have an MDB and an EJB that sends messages to a topic (or queue). JBoss complains that the topic is not bound to the JNDI context.

I want to have the topic/queue to be automatically created at best, or at least to have a standard way to define it, per application (say, in `ejb-jar/META-INF`)

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703040/jms-topic-creation-in-jboss-5-as) and [this blogpost](http://jaikiran.wordpress.com/2006/07/24/how-to-create-a-queuetopic-in-jboss/) show us how to do it in an application server specific way. This surely works, but:

- I want to use the `@MessageDriven` annotation
- I want the setting not to be global for the application server
- I want the setting to be portable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to do this, with JavaEE 5 at least.